# Git Pull Request with latest commit

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I am trying to make a pull request on git hub with only my latest commit. I have tried making a new branch, putting the commit on that branch and then cherry-picking the commit I want on another branch. However, this does not work and any new branch I create (even if I cherry-pick commits) stays the same. I have tried rebase -i but then no commits show up. Could someone please give directions/instructions of how to do this properly?

**Update**
I have two branches, master and develop. I made another branch limit_screen to put in a feature. I have committed the changes to the limit_screen branch. I then make another branch, feature, off of develop. I then cherry-pick the commit from limit_screen. Then I push limit_screen and feature. When I create a new pull request, the number of commits it lists is 8, (the number for the whole project). I would like it just have my last commit (the one I put on limit_screen)

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you are trying to do?  Ideally refer to *actual* repositories so that we can help you get the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only your commit to show up in the pull request, you need to create branch off of master and commit on the new branch and then create pull request. The branches that you are currently working on have commits which have not been merged into master and that's why it shows up in the pull request.